# Is it possible to lock a jpg's size so it can't be stretched when used?

Tags: logo, jpg

My customer wants me to supply them with logos that are "locked" so that when they are imported into a document they can't be stretched/resized. Is that possible?

Comment: Consider the use cases. If this is imported to Word as "letterhead," you might provide a full-page design in eps or tiff file for them to use as a watermark set to "100% size and behind" in a word template and then they simply make their employees use this template for new documents.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that's the problem. I think they use it many different ways. They aren't interested in templates. They want me to perform magic, lol.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot prevent someone from distorting an image because transforming the image is done by the program. You can only tell them not to distort the logo by sending the companies branding guideline or tell them how they can scale/move the logo without distorting the logo.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewH. That's exactly what I've been telling them. I'm gathering evidence to support my case.

Comment: @karen I'd love to see evidence to support theirs :p

Answer (score 1):

To add to Andrew's reply, [JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is already "locked", in a way. So, technically, the file is not a working file if saved in a medium to small size. JPG is a lossy compressed file format, and stretching it will just cause artefacts that will eventually make the image look pretty terrible.

You will probably provide your client with at least two formats for the logo: One scalable (vector, say), and one non-scalable (JPG, PNG). You could tell them to use the JPG/PNG for distribution and keep the scalable logo for internal/official use only.

Comment: It is unusual to think of raster images as "locked" but that is actually what is happening when you rasterize a vector: you lock it in. Obviously this isn't what the OP means, but it is important. Unfortunately, AI and EPS are beyond the training level of many office workers.

Comment: The customer is not editing the actual logo file. My customer puts their jpg logos up on the company intranet so that employees can grab the logo to use it. The problem is, when they place the image in their (I'm assuming Word) document, they are stretching it unproportionately. They have a brand guideline saying not to do this, but you know as well as I do, nobody's reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The logo can be available only as an insertable object that has built-in smartiness (= carries some programmed code). No JPG logo anywhere.This belongs to programmer's sphere of influence. It's not manageable by low profile system administrators or by graphic designers. But it works, if it's supported by company management and the staff already is prohibited to make system changes by policies.

Good policies protect the system but cause easily angriness. Even 10 years ago it was quite irritating to have a password asking dialog under my nose nearly every time when I had got some idea.